# Unable to connect MySQL to a Java application using Eclipse + Wildly 14.0

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, wildfly

I am unable to connect a Java application to a local MySQL 8 database, running macOS. I am using Eclipse and deploying on WildFly 16.0. As I deploy my app the console spits the following error

```
18:15:00,537 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "MYAPP")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.MYAPP is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/MYAPP is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql]"
    ]
}
18:15:00,602 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "MYAPP")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.MYAPP is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/MYAPP is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql]"
    ]
}
```

My `WildFly/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main/module.xml` contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Also in this directory is my Java connector with the same name as declared in the file.

And my `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` contains:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MYAPP" pool-name="MYAPP" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYAPP</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>MYPASS</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>

...


<drivers>
                    <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
```

And inside my Eclipse project inside the `Java Resouces/src/META-INF/persistence.xml` contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MYAPP">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MYAPP</jta-data-source>
        <class>dl.USER</class>
        <class>dl.POST</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>      
        </properties>   
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I can't see what is wrong with this but as for the log attached above it can't find the MySQL connector.

Comment: please also add the connection pool config

Comment: Did you edit the raw XML or did you use CLI or the web interface to add the data source?

Answer (score 0):

Hello the issue is the name of the module:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
```

And you're trying to connect to:

```
"jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql
```

Comment: What file should I change and put there?

Comment: The problem is that I haven't defined a module called `jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql` I only defined `com.mysql` and I don't know where that comes from

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name attribute in the `<driver>` definition to plain *mysql*

`<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">`

and also the corresponding reference in the `<datasource>` section to

`<driver>mysql</driver>`

It seems that because the name element is type of xs:token the dot is somehow replaced to underscore.